# Rds cross region read delays

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We have an rds instance in us-east-1, the applications that access the rds are in us-east-1 and us-east-2. the two regions have vpc peering. we are load balancing the request received by using route53 weighted routing policy. we are experiencing 10 ms delay when communicating across regions. currently, these 10 ms delays are acceptable between microservices. but when the applications in region2 are accessing rds, we are facing a considerable delay. (due to the large amount of database calls of hibernate ). Are there any was to reduce this database latency ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have cross-region databases and reading from slave / read-replicas then expect some delays. This is not technology issue but physics problem as data has to physically travel from A to B. The latency will grow as you move these points (A & B) further away from each other.

A solution to reduce this latency is to use cache layer. All the first reads will be from database (cross-region) but subsequent ones can be from Redis cache for e.g.